# Flutter problem: overflowed by 61 pixels on the right?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to implement a ListView of Rows in Flutter, more or less like this.
[image]

I found a sample code, and modified it into this:

```
body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 100.0,
                      color: Colors.blue[200],
                      child: Row (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Artikel 1", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0)),
                          Text("Ini adalah contoh artikel pada listview dengan versi custom", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Full code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anta40/6ab1e951cf716a6f7d326bf3d25aa808).

And here is the result:

[image]

How to fix the "overflowed by 61 pixels on the right" error?

Comment: I'll suggest using a table here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html
If you want a row widget, that is not overflowed you should use an expanded widget or flexible

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a CTRL+C and CTRL+V.

The First Container has a Row and should have a Column.

```
                     child: Row (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Artikel 1", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0)),
                          Text("Ini adalah contoh artikel pada listview dengan versi custom", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
                        ],
                      ),
```

Should be:

```
                     child: Column (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Artikel 1", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0)),
                          Text("Ini adalah contoh artikel pada listview dengan versi custom", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
                        ],
                      ),
```